# why we have to divide r! for one time rather than many time?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I want clear my vague mind about combination.
Let's say find the combinations of (A,B,C,D,E,F) persons for $4$ chairs.

Now the main thing is if you have to eliminate those over counting situations, you have to divide the permutation with $4!$. Which means:

$\frac{6P4}{4!}$

My question is why $4!$ for one time.Shouldn't it be every time when you take $4$ things out of $6$ I mean (A,B,C,D)/$4!$ then (C,D,E,F)/$4!$........... and it goes on and on.

Please clear my mind within simple words.

Comment: Note that $\frac{X+Y}{r!} = \frac{X}{r!} + \frac{Y}{r!}$. Dividing all summands of a sum by a number is the same as dividing the whole sum by that number.

Comment: If you are asking about how many ways you can select four of six people to be seated, then the answer is $$\binom{6}{4} = \frac{6!}{4!2!}$$ If you are asking how many ways you can select four of six people to be seated, then seat them in four seats arranged in a row, the answer is $$\binom{6}{4}4! = \frac{6!}{4!2!} \cdot 4! = \frac{6!}{2!} = \frac{6!}{(6 - 4)!} = P(6, 4)$$

Comment: I don't want answers.I want explanation of that answer.

Comment: It seems that you are looking for the number of combinations, not combinations themselves. In this connection it is unclear what do you mean by writing "(A,B,C,D)/4!".

Comment: I meant the number of combination of (A,B,C,D). Somehow it makes sense to me that number of combinations of 4 or 5 items is 1.But I feel confused by the formula when you have take r from n and figure out the number of combination.